# Pipe raw HTTP stream to PHP r/w stream

Tags: php, sockets, stream

I was wondering if it is possible at all to get an HTTP request that was made by a browser towards a PHP running as Apache module into a read- and writable stream.

I did some research and testing and it appears that the standard streams like `://stdin/-out/-error` and `://input` may only be available running PHP in CLI mode [[link]](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.io-streams.php).

What I want to do is reading the raw HTTP request. Also, this should happen in a read/write stream so that I can write some bytes directly as response to the request. Possible?

Comment: if have you found your answers, please share here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than running PHP in CLI, it's not possible to achieve reading/writing raw streams that way.